# Can a rocket igniter rated for 12v and 3 amps be powered with a 4v battery at 9 amps?

Tags: voltage, power, current

I have a rocket motor igniter that says it requires a 12 volt battery at 3 amps. Since power is I x V, and power is really what heats up the wire that starts the igniter, is it possible that I could use a lower voltage battery, but use a much larger current to compensate, and have the same power?

Comment: An igniter is basically a fuse. The key concept for an all-fire specification will be related to the action integral. For a 1st-order estimate, the time required is proportional to the current-squared and since the current will the one third as much with one third the voltage, this means 9 times as long to fire. However, this provides much more time to dissipate without firing. So if it works at all, it will work very much more slowly -- well more than 10X as long to fire it. You could try the idea. The time required, even if it works, won't be nearly as predictable. Unsafe even, perhaps.

Comment: Presumably a boost converter would be able to fire the igniter as long as it could put out the required power for long enough. Other answers have explained why 4V will probably not do it reliably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Ohm's law you can modify the power formula.

$$ P = V I = (IR)I = I^2R \tag 1$$
$$ P = V I = V \frac {V}{R} = \frac {V^2}{R} \tag 2 $$

Since your R is constant then dropping the voltage will reduce the power.

> I have a rocket motor igniter that says it requires a 12 volt battery at 3 amps.

We can calculate the igniter resistance as \$ R = \frac{V}{I} = \frac {12}{3} = 4 \ \Omega \$. From (1) above we see that \$ P = \frac {V^2}{R} = \frac {12^2}{4} = 36 \ \text W \$.

At 4 V the power dissipated would be \$ P = \frac {V^2}{R} = \frac {4^2}{4} = 4 \ \text W \$. Note the 'square' relationship: dividing the voltage by 3 divides the power by 9.